# PHP Iterate Variable for Array in While Loop

Tags: php, loops, variables, while-loop

I pulled down an array of business services from my server and wanted to display the data in a form so it could be edited and sent to another page.

I wanted to assign a variable to each piece of data (ie. input type ='text'  name='service$c') and iterate the value of $c so that it would assign a new value each time (ex. service1, service2, etc.) so that when the data posted to the next page I could retrieve it by those variable names.

I found that if I put something like " for ($i=1; $i<20 $i++) "inside the while loop, each individual bit of data in my array would print 20 times and if I took it outside of the while loop, the while loop $c would equal "service1" each time.

I did work out a solution, but I'm wondering if it's kind of hackey...It works, but I'm wondering if I could have done it better.

```
//Create the form
echo "<form action='changeservices2.php' method='post'>";

//Print Out My Array
while ($result_ar = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    //Shorten the variable
    $a=$result_ar['service'];

    //Start at 1
    $b=1;

    //Iterate
    $c = $b+$d;
    echo "<input type ='text'  name='service$c' value='$a' ><br>";

    //Since the first variable is null, I needed to help change it
    if (is_null($c)) {$c=1;}
    $d=$c;

}


echo "<input type ='submit'  value='submit' ><br>";
echo "</form>";
```

It works, I'm just wondering if I'm missing a more elegant / simple solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use array-style names:

```
<input type="text" name="service[]" value="$a">
```

Then `$_POST['service']` will be an array that you can loop over.

Comment: That works, much better!  Thanks for untangling it for me.

Comment: @user6307157 if this answers your question, you can mark it as accepted (the green V). It is rewarding for the one who answered you and will show the futurs readers that they can use this answer